# Has anyone succeeded in formalizing the notion of a complete vector space? (Not using topological ideas).

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

In order theory, we have the concept of a *lattice*, which is defined as consisting of an underlying set $L$ together with two binary operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$. Now when $L$ is finite, the concept of a lattice works great. For example, if $X$ is a finite set, then the lattice generated by the singletons of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is $\mathcal{P}(X)$. However, if $X$ is infinite, then this is not the case. Thus, a more useful concept in the infinite case is the concept of a *complete lattice*, which consists of an underlying set $L$ together with two unary operation $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$ defined on the powerset of $L$. Sure enough, we have that for $X$ an arbitrary set, not necessarily finite, the complete lattice generated by the singletons of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

I reckon vector spaces have a similar issues to lattices. When a vector space is finite-dimensional, everything is great. However for *infinite-dimensional* ones, we really need some sort of unary summation operator $\sum.$

Here's an example where this really matter. Lets adopt, for the moment, all the usual definitions (in particular, let *basis* and *linear combination* mean what they usually mean, etc.) and allow $V$ to denote the vector space of all functions

$$[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$

Furthermore, consider the family $e : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $i \in [0,1]$ all $x \in [0,1]$ we have $$x = i \rightarrow e_i(x) = 1,\quad x \neq i \rightarrow e_i(x) = 0.$$

It follows that $e$ cannot span $V$, since only those functions $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with finite support can be written as a linear combination of the elements of $e$. So $e$ is not a basis for $V$.

However, it is obvious how to write any function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as an "infinitary" linear combination using $e$. Namely

$$f = \sum_{i \in [0,1]} f(i)e_i.$$

So I think that we need a notion of "complete vector space," meaning a vector space equipped with an infinitary summation operator $\sum$ subject to certain reasonable constraints. Furthermore, concepts like "linear combination" and "basis" really need to be defined differently in a complete vector space, because infinite sums are allowed.

However, its not clear how to formalize this idea.

**Has anyone succeeded in formalizing the notion of a "complete vector spaces"?**

---

*Discussion*. Let us first note that **this is probably not a topological idea,** for the following reason. Suppose $X$ is a set, possible infinite, and $K$ is a field not equipped with any particular topology. Then there ought to exist a "complete vector space" of all functions $X \rightarrow K$. However as far as I can see, there is no topology in sight.

Secondly, if $V$ is a complete vector space over a field $K$, then it is not clear what the domain of $\sum$ should be. Taking the domain as $\mathcal{P}(V)$ isn't going to work; after all, if $x \in V$ is nonzero, we don't want to demand that the sum of $\{kx \mid k \in K\}$ exist. That would be too much to ask! So the domain of $\sum$ really needs to be a proper subset of $\mathcal{P}(V).$ Actually, this isn't really the natural thing to do. It would be better if the domain of $\sum$ were a proper subset of the collection of all multisets in $V$.

Comment: Well, that's what a topological vector space gives you. Some infinite sums converge. For your example, the natural topology to consider would be the product topology, and hey presto, you have a summable family $\{f(x)\cdot e_x\}$ there. If you wish, you can always endow the field with the discrete topology.

Comment: @DanielFischer, wait if $X$ is an arbitrary set and $K$ an arbitrary field, what do you mean by the product topology on the set $V$ of all functions $X \rightarrow K$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, so you're saying to view $V$ as the topological space $\prod_{x \in X} K$, where $K$ is viewed as having the discrete topology?

Comment: Right. Unless you have a reason to prefer a different topology (very often, you have, if $K$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ or so).

Comment: @DanielFischer, that sounds reasonable. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: You would like to formalize a topological notion without using topological ideas? This will be hard. You might be interested in the monadic description of Banach spaces or rather their unit balls: There you have an infinite, but countable summation operator satisfying the usual laws.

Comment: @DanielFischer, in your approach, how do we define an uncountably infinite sum of vectors?

Comment: You have the directed set of finite subsets of the family $W$. For every finite subset $F$, let $s_F = \sum\limits_{v\in F} v$. The net $(s_F)$ either converges (then we have a sum $s = \sum\limits_{v\in W} v$) or not, then $\sum\limits_{v\in W} v$ does not exist.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I think maybe that's not going to work. If $\mathbb{R}$ is given the discrete topology, then singletons are open in $\sum_{x \in [0,1]} \mathbb{R}$. Ergo $\sum_{x \in [0,1]} e(x)$ won't converge, because no finite subset $F$ of $[0,1]$ has the property that $\sum_{x \in F} e(x) \in \{f\},$ where $f$ is defined as the unique function $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I had to edit the previous comment like 100x, so if it didn't make sense the first time, try reading it again.

Comment: @DanielFischer, on second thoughts according to the definition given at the [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) page, perhaps I was wrong to assert that the singletons are open in $\sum_{x \in [0,1]} \mathbb{R}$. It seems I was thinking of the [box topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology).

Comment: Yes. In the product topology, a neighbourhood constrains only finitely many $x$. For every finite set $\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\} \subset [0,1]$, you have a finite sum that coincides with $f$ in all $x_i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, is it true that, given a topological field $K$, the set of all functions $X \rightarrow K$ becomes a topological vector space with the pointwise operations? In particular, how do we know the pointwise operations are continuous?

Comment: Directly from the definition of the product topology. $f \colon Y \to \prod_i X_i$ is continuous if and only if all $\pi_i\circ f \colon Y \to X_i$ are continuous. The operations are continuous $K\times K \to K$ (since $K$ is a topological field), so the pointwise operations are continuous on the product. Slightly more general, a product of topological vector spaces always is a topological vector space.

Comment: @DanielFischer, not really getting it. Why are we taking a product of $X_i$'s? I think we should be taking a product of $K$'s.

Comment: @DanielFischer, also, most of my previous summation symbols in the comments were meant to be $\prod$ symbols. Sorry about that.

Comment: The $X_i$s were just for generality, the property is true for _all_ products of topological spaces, here we're dealing with the special case that $X_i = K$ for all $i$. The short text version is: since addition and multiplication are continuous in each factor of the product space, they are continuous on the product space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned in the comments that actually, topological vector spaces do the trick. The key point is that a field $K$ can always be viewed as a topological field with the discrete topology, and thus it can be viewed as a topological vector space over itself. This isn't very exciting if we're only interested in $K^n$ for finite $n$, since $K^n$ just ends up having the discrete topology. However, if we're interested in infinite powers like $K^I$ for $I$ an infinite set, then things become much more interesting. In particular, $K^I$ no longer has the discrete topology (see also, [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) versus [box topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology)). This means, among other things, that we can uniquely decompose any $f \in K^I$ as an infinite sum

$$f=\sum_{i \in I}f(i)e_i,$$

where $e$ is defined as in the original question.